# C# - Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState not working as expected

Tags: c#, uwp

I am developing a simple Universal Windows App using C#. I have a **RichEditBox** and I found a weird behavior when using **Control+I** key combination, which for some reason inserts a **Tab** (*is that expected?*). Because I wanted the combination of keys to toggle Italic font style, I thought the best way was through the KeyDown event.
So, this is my code:

```
    private void richbox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("\nKeyDown : " + e.Key.ToString());
        if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Tab)
        {
            richbox.Document.Selection.TypeText("\t");
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) == Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
        {
            //If Control is pressed down, check if current key is B,I,U...
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(" => Control is down!");
            switch (e.OriginalKey)
            {
                case VirtualKey.B:
                    toogleBold();
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
                case VirtualKey.I:
                    e.Handled = true;
                    toogleItalic(); 
                    break;
                case VirtualKey.U:
                    toogleUnderline();
                    e.Handled = true;
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

My problem is, the condition on the **Else If** is not always true when I press the Control key. I would like to understand why and what could I do to fix it.
If I run the code and I press the control key a few times, this is the output:

> KeyDown : Control => Control is down!
>
> KeyDown : Control
>
> KeyDown : Control => Control is down!
>
> KeyDown : Control
>
> ...

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.keyroutedeventargs "Provides data for the *KeyUp* and KeyDown routed events." ... You are seeing (based upon your initial post) "key down, key up, key down, key up."  ... Are you sure you're attached to keydown? method naming appears so, but I can't see where you're adding it.

Comment: @Aaron On XAML I have this code for the RichEditBox, `<RichEditBox x:Name="richbox" Margin="0,30,0,0" KeyDown="richbox_KeyDown"></RichEditBox>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your code and used debugger output to see what the actual state of Ctrl is in those situations:

```
var state = Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control);
Debug.WriteLine(state);
```

What I found out is that the second time you press the key, its state is not **Down**, but **Down|Locked**, more specifically `Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down | Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Locked`. It turns out `CoreVirtualKeyStates` is a flag enum and it can have multiple values at the same time. In this case you are comparing with `==` which means you don't get a match. You can first use the `HasFlag` method or bitwise AND (`&`) to get the right value out and then compare and you will be good to go!

That means either this:

```
else if ( Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control).
             HasFlag( CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down ) )
{
    //rest of the code
}
```

Or this:

```
else if ( 
  ( Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) &
    Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down )
    == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down )
{ 
    //rest of the code
}
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. You are right, it either has **Down** state or **Down,Locked** state. As the documentation says _All keys support the Locked state (not just the standard Caps Lock and Num Lock keys)._, but I don't get what the Locked state means for a key such Control. Do you know why the locked state is flagged?

Comment: This is the correct answer. The bitwise operation makes all sense, but I would assume this `else if(Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) != Windows.UI.Core.CoreVirtualKeyStates.None)` also does the job, since when the key is pressed down it only has **Down** or **Down,Locked** states, as mentioned by Martin. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have been searching for the reason as well but I have not yet found an explanation. What I found out is that for Ctrl and similar controls it first sets `Down` only and on second press `Down|Locked`, but for keys like `A` letter it behaves quite weird - for example when the letter gets in the locked state and then you press `Shift` only (with `A` released), the `A` key will still report as Locked. That means that simple check for `None` is not necessarily the safest solution, rather the `HasFlag` method seems to be the sure way out.

Comment: I think the behavior you get for key `A` is the same I have noticed for `Control`. If I output its state when using other keys rather Control, it has Locked or None states. If Control is Locked, it will stay like that until you press it. When you release it and use other keys it will report as None state, until you press it again. I will just use the `HasFlag`, it seems to be the safest.

Comment: Yes, after further testing it seems so. Apparently the system keeps track of "toggles" for all keys not only for Caps Lock. And this works system-wide, not only for a given app.