# Can't write to file after opening it through drag and drop

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a problem with my drag and drop, I can drag in a file and display the text in a textbox but when I want to try and change the content of it and save the file it says that I only have permissions to read it and can't save to it again. From what I understand this is standard behaviour for drag & drop.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Pickers;
using Windows.System.Threading;
using Windows.UI.WindowManagement;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation;
using System.Net.Mime;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using System.ServiceModel.Channels;
using Windows.Media.Capture.Frames;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Core;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=402352&clcid=0x409

namespace Labb3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        string title; //Håler i titeln på den öppnade filen
        StorageFile storageFile; //Hållere i den öppnade filen
        int buttonDown; //Används för att returnera om en kanpp är nertryckt när vi släpper indragna filer

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Knappen för ny fil
            if (sender == NewFileButton)
            {
                //Splittar titeln för att kolla om filen är sparad eller inte 
                string[] checkTitle = Title.Text.Split(".txt");

                //Kollar om filen inte är sparad
                if (checkTitle[checkTitle.Length - 1] == "*")
                {
                    //Medelanderuta som kollar om användaren vill spara filen
                    MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog("Spara fil?");

                    //Knappen ja sparar undan filen 
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ja", async x =>
                    {
                        File(NewFileButton);
                        ResetValues();

                    }));

                    //Knappen nej tömmer rutan
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Nej", x =>
                    {
                        //Tömmer rutan 
                        myText.Text = "";
                        storageFile = null;
                        ResetValues();
                    }));

                    //Avbryt återgår till tidigare text
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Avbryt"));

                    //Visar medelanderutan
                    await message.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Behöver texten inte sparas töms rutan
                    myText.Text = "";
                    storageFile = null;
                }
            }
            //Knappen för att öppna en fil
            else if (sender == OpenFileButton)
            {
                //Splittar titeln för att kolla om filen är sparad eller inte 
                string[] checkTitle = Title.Text.Split(".txt");

                //Kollar om texten i textrutan behöver sparas
                if (checkTitle[checkTitle.Length-1] == "*")
                {

                    //Visar en medelanderuta med texten "Spara fil"
                    MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog("Spara fil?");

                    //Knappen sparar nuvarande text/fil och öppnar en ny
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ja", x => {
                        File(OpenFileButton);
                        ResetValues();
                        OpenFile();
                    }));

                    //Knappen tömmer textrutan och öppnar en ny fil
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Nej", x => {
                        ResetValues();
                        OpenFile();
                    }));

                    //Knappen avbryter och återgår till den tidigare texten
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Avbryt"));

                    //Visar medelandelistan
                    await message.ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    //Behöver inte den nuvarande texten/filen sparas öppnas utforskaren för att välja fil
                    OpenFile();
                }
            }
            //Knappanen för att spara
            else if (sender == SaveFileButton)
            {
                File(SaveFileButton);
            }
            //Knappen för att spara som 
            else if (sender == SaveLocalButton)
            {
                File(SaveLocalButton);
            }
            //Avsluta programmet
            else if (sender == ClearButton)
            {
                //Splittar titeln för att kolla om filen är sparad eller inte 
                string[] checkTitle = Title.Text.Split(".txt");
                
                //Kollar om filen inte är sparad
                if (checkTitle[checkTitle.Length - 1] == "*")
                {
                    //Visar en medelanderuta med medelande "Spara fil?"
                    MessageDialog message = new MessageDialog("Spara fil?");

                    //Ja för att spar fil
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Ja", async x =>
                    {
                        File(ClearButton);                        
                    }));

                    //Nej för att inte spara fil
                    message.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Nej"));

                    //Visar rutan 
                    await message.ShowAsync();
                }
                //Stänger programmet om filen inte ändrats
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        }

        private async void myText_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Delar upp vektorn för att hitta mellandslag 
            string[] Antal = myText.Text.Split(new string[] { " ", "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            //Splittar texten för att hitta antal rader
            string[] Rows = myText.Text.Split(new string[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            int antal = 0;

            //Lopar igenom vektorn antal för att se hur många tecekn den innehåller
            for (int i = 0; i < Antal.Length; i++)
            {
                if (Antal[i] != " ")
                {
                    antal += Antal[i].Length;
                }
            }

            //Skriver ut antal rader
            Antalrader.Text = "Antal rader: " + Rows.Length;

            //Skriver ut antal tecken
            Antaltecken.Text = "Antal tecken: " + antal;

            //Skriver ut antal tecekn med mellanslag
            Antalteckenmellanslag.Text = "Antal tecken med mellanslag: " + myText.Text.Length;

            //Skriver ut antal ord
            Antalord.Text = "Antal ord: " + Antal.Length;

            //Kollar om det finns en tidigare öppnad fil
            if (storageFile != null)
            {
                //Hämtar ut texten ur den hämtade filen för att kunna jämföra med texten i rutan och se om de har olika innehåll
                var Text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(storageFile);

                //Sätter ut asterisken för att visa att texten i dokumentet har ändrats och inte sparats
                if (title == Title.Text && Text != myText.Text)
                {
                    Title.Text += "*";
                }
                else if (Text == myText.Text)
                {
                    Title.Text = title;
                }
            }
            //Sätter ut asterisken för att visa att texten i dokumentet har ändrats och inte sparats
            else if (antal == 1)
            {
                Title.Text += "*";
            }
            else if(antal == 0 && storageFile == null)
            {
                Title.Text = "Namlös.txt";
            }
        }

        //Funktion för att återställa texter och dess värden i applikationen 
        public void ResetValues()
        {
            Title.Text = "Namlös.txt";
            Antalrader.Text = "Antal rader: 0";
            Antaltecken.Text = "Antal tecken: 0";
            Antalteckenmellanslag.Text = "Antal tecken med mellanslag: 0";
            Antalord.Text = "Antal ord: 0";
        }

        //Funktion för att spara till filer
        public async void File(object send)
        {
            //Kollar om det finns en tidigare öppnad fil eller om användaren har tryckt på SaveLocalButton
            if (storageFile == null || send == SaveLocalButton)
            {
                //Instansierar en FileSavePicker
                var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();

                //Talar om att det bara går att spara filer som .txt
                fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".txt", new List<string> { ".txt" });

                //Öppar upp utforskaren (file explorer) för att användaren ska kunna välja namn och plats 
                //för att spara filen 
                var result = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

                //Kollar om användaren har valt att spara en fil
                if (result != null)
                {
                    //Hämtar texten i textrutan och lägger till det i den valda filen 
                    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(result, myText.Text);

                    //Sätter sidans title till dokumentets namn
                    Title.Text = result.DisplayName + ".txt";

                    //Sparar undan titeln för att kunna kolla om den har ändrats och behöver sparas
                    title = Title.Text;

                    //Sparar undan filen för att kunna spara till tidigare öppnad fil 
                    storageFile = result;
                }
            }
            else if(send == SaveFileButton || send == ClearButton)
            {
                //Sparar till tidigare öppnade fil
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, myText.Text);

                //Sätter om titeln på sidan till den tidigare sparade så asterisken försvinner och den markeras som sparad
                Title.Text = title;
            }
        }

        //Funktion för att öppna filer
        public async void OpenFile()
        {
            //Instansierar en FileOpenPicker för att kunna öppna
            var fileOapenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();

            //Begränsar applikationen till att bara kunna öppna .txt filer
            fileOapenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

            //Öppnar utforskaren (file explorern) för att kunna välja en fil
            var result = await fileOapenPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

            //Kollar om användaren hämtade en fil
            if (result != null)
            {
                //Hämtar texten ur filen
                var Text = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(result);

                //Sätter filens text i textrutan
                myText.Text = Text;

                //Sätter filens title som sidans titel
                Title.Text = result.DisplayName + ".txt";

                //Sparar undan titel för att senare kunna kolla om den skiljer sig från orginalet
                //Då kan man se om filen behöver sparas
                title = Title.Text;

                //Sparar undan resultatet från den sparade filen för att kunna skriva över den nya texten på tidigare vaöd fil
                storageFile = result;
            }
        }

        //Tillåter att vi kan dra in filer
        //Taget från följande video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rREv3Hq5tI&t=1017s
        private void StackPanel_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            e.AcceptedOperation = Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataPackageOperation.Copy;

            //Egenskapare som gör det möjligt att dra in en fil
            e.DragUIOverride.Caption = "Add (+)";
            e.DragUIOverride.IsCaptionVisible = true;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsContentVisible = true;
            e.DragUIOverride.IsGlyphVisible = true;
        }

        //Tillåter att släppa och hämta innehållet ur en fil och visa det i en textruta
        //Taget från följande video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-rREv3Hq5tI&t=1017s
        //Samt tråden https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66715836/c-sharp-uwp-read-from-dragged-file
        private async void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
            {
                var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();

                if (items.Count > 0)
                {
                    var File = items[0] as StorageFile;
                    string content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(File);
                    
                    // (ctrl) Lägger till filens innehåll i slutet på den text som finns
                    if (buttonDown == 1)
                    {
                        myText.Text +=  content;
                        buttonDown = 0;
                    }
                    // (shift) Lägger till vid markörens plats
                    else if (buttonDown == 2)
                    {
                        //Lägger till vid markörens plats (fixa)
                        /*var currentPosition = myText.SelectionStart;
                        myText.Text += myText.Text.Insert(currentPosition, content);*/
                        buttonDown = 0;
                    }
                    //Öppnar upp filen 
                    else
                    {
                        myText.Text = content;
                        Title.Text = File.Name;
                        title = Title.Text;
                        storageFile = File;

                        //Fixar så de frågar om den ska spara när man trycket på X eller avslutar programmet 
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Lyssnare för att se om användaren har tryckt ner en knapp när vi drar in en fil 
        private void StackPanel_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Sätter tillbaka kontrollen för nedtryckta knappar 
            buttonDown = 0;

            /*Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetAsyncKey(VirtualKey.Shift) & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtyalKeyStates.Down
             Kollar om en knapp är nertryckt, i detta fall shift*/
            //Hittade lösningen i följande tråd https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784989/c-sharp-window-current-corewindow-getkeystate-not-working-as-expected
            if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Control && (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetAsyncKeyState(VirtualKey.Control) & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
            {
                buttonDown = 1;
            }
            else if (e.Key == VirtualKey.Shift && (Window.Current.CoreWindow.GetAsyncKeyState(VirtualKey.Shift) & CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down) == CoreVirtualKeyStates.Down)
            {
                buttonDown = 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any chance you remove unnecessary code and leave just enough to reproduce the probelm?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that reads the droped file:

```
private async void StackPanel_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.StorageItems))
            {
                var items = await e.DataView.GetStorageItemsAsync();
                if(items.Count > 0)
                {
                    var File = items[0] as StorageFile;
                    string content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(File);
                    
                    // (ctrl) Lägger till filens innehåll i slutet på den text som finns
                    if(buttonDown == 1)
                    {
                        myText.Text +=  content;
                        buttonDown = 0;
                    }
                    // (shift) Lägger till vid markörens plats
                    else if (buttonDown == 2)
                    {
                        //Lägger till vid markörens plats (fixa)
                        /*var currentPosition = myText.SelectionStart;
                        myText.Text += myText.Text.Insert(currentPosition, content);*/
                        buttonDown = 0;
                    }
                    //Öppnar upp filen 
                    else
                    {
                        myText.Text = content;
                        Title.Text = File.Name;
                        title = Title.Text;
                        storageFile = File;

                        //Fixar så de frågar om den ska spara när man trycket på X eller avslutar programmet 
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is the code that try to save the file when i click the save button:

´´´
public async void File(object send)
{
//Kollar om det finns en tidigare öppnad fil eller om användaren har tryckt på SaveLocalButton
if (storageFile == null || send == SaveLocalButton)
{
//Instansierar en FileSavePicker
var fileSavePicker = new FileSavePicker();

```
            //Talar om att det bara går att spara filer som .txt
            fileSavePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add(".txt", new List<string> { ".txt" });

            //Öppar upp utforskaren (file explorer) för att användaren ska kunna välja namn och plats 
            //för att spara filen 
            var result = await fileSavePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

            //Kollar om användaren har valt att spara en fil
            if (result != null)
            {
                //Hämtar texten i textrutan och lägger till det i den valda filen 
                await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(result, myText.Text);

                //Sätter sidans title till dokumentets namn
                Title.Text = result.DisplayName + ".txt";

                //Sparar undan titeln för att kunna kolla om den har ändrats och behöver sparas
                title = Title.Text;

                //Sparar undan filen för att kunna spara till tidigare öppnad fil 
                storageFile = result;
            }
        }
        else if(send == SaveFileButton || send == ClearButton)
        {
            //Sparar till tidigare öppnade fil
            await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(storageFile, myText.Text);

            //Sätter om titeln på sidan till den tidigare sparade så asterisken försvinner och den markeras som sparad
            Title.Text = title;
        }
    }
```

´´´
´´´

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).